# Problemas ao adicionar side menu em projeto já iniciado

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic, ionic3

Estou começando com **Ionic**, tenho uma dúvida.

Criei um projeto em branco **"ionic start projeto blank"**, e consegui criar a tela principal do meu aplicativo, apenas um LOGO com botão "ENTRAR" para entrar no app, mas gostaria de adicionar na pagina ENTRAR, um side menu. Mas já tem um tempão que pesquiso mas não encontro, acredito que seja possível.

Eu apenas gostaria de ter o SideMenu na tela principal, porém não é a tela que inicia o app, logo não pude criar com o modelo sidemenu.   É possível eu adicionar um SIDEMENU em um projeto ja criado em blank?

Estou realmente procurando mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Mostre o código fonte do aplicativo.

Comment: [ "...não pude criar com o modelo sidemenu..." ], Quando você tentou criar com o modelo de side menu o Ionic te retornou algum erro? Se sim poste o screen shot aqui pra melhorar sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Bom Felipe, você pode fazer de duas formas:

1a - Criar o app com o modelo de sidemenu e alterar a página principal:

- Cria o app com o modelo de sidemenu
- Gera uma nova página com `ionic generate page nome_da_pagina`
- Vai no arquivo `app.component.ts` e define a propriedade `rootPage` com essa nova página criada (no momento que você abrir o arquivo deve estar como MenuPage ou algo assim).

Quando você testar você vai ver que a primeira página que será aberta é essa nova criada, depois basta colocar um evento de click no botão e no método utilizar o `NavController` para dar um push da nova view (que será `MenuPage` e terá o menu criado pelo Ionic). Dê uma olhada na [documentação](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) desse caso.

2a - Continuar da forma e gerar uma página que será o menu.

- Nesse caso, gere uma nova página que servirá como menu.
- Siga as instruções da [documentação](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#menus) para fazer o menu de acordo com o padrão.
- Coloque um evento de click no botão de "Entrar" que mudará a `rootPage` para a página do menu.

Como você está no início, recomendo seguir da primeira forma.

Comment: Obrigado por responder Noeyeat, fiz como voce disse na primeira opção, mas dá erro , definindo a rootpage como a que criei, ele automaticamente importa a page acima, mas mesmo assim dá erro. Tem algo mais que eu precise modificar?

Comment: @FelipeXST qual erro que dá? Só falando que tem erro não consigo te ajudar